# How do I use goto attribute in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

Does this work? This is in the start method, using photon for networking. I am trying to wait till room time is initialised.

```
 Wait:
        if (!PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties.ContainsKey("StartTime") )
        {
            goto Wait;
        }
        else
        {
            goto Continue;
        }
        Continue:
        startTime = double.Parse(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties["StartTime"].ToString());
```

Comment: Be aware that ["attribute" has a specific meaning in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/), so you shouldn't call other things "attributes". Re your question: from what I've seen of Unity, i would expect you to check this kind of thing in an `Update()` method, rather than having a loop somewhere (which would be better off as a `while` loop rather than using `goto`, but still probably isn't the right way to go).

Comment: That's not an _Attribute_, that's a _Statement_ (like `for` or `switch`). Generally code with `goto` statements tends to grow into an unholy mess (known as _spaghetti_). Search for "goto considered harmful"). In general they are best avoided. It's very rare that you might find a good use for `goto`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general I would say avoid using `goto` **at all**!

In almost all cases I can think of any other solution in my eyes is cleaner and better to read and maintain than `goto` jumps. It is more a "relic" of former times. In the examples of [`goto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto) might be the only use-case where it **might** make sense .. within a `switch-case` or to break out of a nested loop .. but even there you can find other (in my eyes better) solutions.

Your code basically equals writing

```
while(!PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties.ContainsKey("StartTime")) { }

startTime = double.Parse(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties["StartTime"].ToString());
```

And latest now I hope you see the **huge issue**: You have a neverending `while` loop!

- Inside the `while` the condition is never changed
- And it can not be changed from the outside either since you run this in `Start` so the entire Unity main thread is blocked until that loop ends. I'm not 100% sure but afaik `PhotonNetwork` needs the Unity main thread to dispatch the received events -> your condition probably will never ever become true.

---

You should rather use a [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). A Coroutine is like a small temporary `Update` method. It is **not** async but rather runs right after `Update` until the next `yield` statement and thereby still allows your Unity main thread to continue rendering and doesn't freeze your entire application.

```
// Yes, if you make Start return IEnumerator
// then Unity automatically runs it as a Coroutine!
private IEnumerator Start ()
{
    // https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html
    // This basically does what it says: Wait until a condition is true
    // In a Coroutine the yield basically tells Unity
    // "pause" this routine, render this frame and continue from here in the next frame
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties.ContainsKey("StartTime"));

    startTime = double.Parse(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties["StartTime"].ToString());

    ....
}
```

---

Even better than checking this **every frame** in a loop **at all** would actually be

- check this **once** in start
- only check it again **once** after the room properties have actually changed

So something like e.g.

```
bool isInitialzed;

private void Start ()
{
    TryGetStartTime (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties);
}

private void TryGetStartTime(Hashtable properties)
{
    if(!properties.Contains("StartTime")) return;

    startTime = double.Parse(properties["StartTime"].ToString());
    isInitialzed = true;
}

public void OnRoomPropertiesUpdate(Hashtable propertiesThatChanged)
{
    TryGetStartTime (propertiesThatChanged);
}
```

And rather make other methods wait until `isInitialized` is true.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation, this helps me a lot.   Edit: wow! I just learnt a lot, from this ans. Particularly start as an IEnumerator